# For Each x ... Next Vs. For Each x ... Next x

Tags: vb.net, syntax

Normally, I program .NET in C#, but currently I am updating a project written in VB.NET and have noticed a curious syntax being used in `For Each` loops.

Is there any difference between

```
For Each x in collection.Items
    ...
Next
```

and

```
For Each x in collection.Items
    ...
Next x
```

?

I have seen both in the code here and was curious why someone would use the second variation.

Comment: AFAIK, it's only to help keep very large (nested) loops easy to read...

Comment: I can't find any reference to it but I think that in VB6 `Next` was faster than `Next x` - I doubt that is still true in VB.NET though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specified like so on the MSDN Reference:

> You can optionally specify element in the Next statement. This
>   improves the readability of your program, especially if you have
>   nested For Each loops. You must specify the same variable as the one
>   that appears in the corresponding For Each statement.

Original can be found here - fifth para under Remarks section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The second version can be clearer for the reader, particularly where there are lots of nested loops. There is no other reason for it. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the functionality; it's just to help avoid mistakes and for backwards-compatibility with VB6. Personally, I never use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's there to annotate which `next` belongs with which `for`. I'm not sure if the compiler checks to see that the `for` and the `next` match, but conceivably it could fail if they don't